# OS X Server keeps DHCP DISCOVER even with no client in the net. how to stop?

Tags: logging, dhcp, netboot

I have trouble with DHCP release, this server keeps NETBOOT or DHCP DISCOVER even if the specified device was logged out, and its wlan modul is tourned off. Wich leads me to - that the server is offering a connection for netbooting. So when turning on netboot service filtering with no specified mac-address, the DHCP DISCOVER stops until i turn filtering off.
the game starts again :(

With a little search i found out http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3678?viewlocale=en_US wich tells how to analyse netboot problems, but i did not find out how to stop the not connected device asking for netbooting.

i checked all settings in that device, checked cables, tryed static ip (even this was working, so dhcp keeps same with given clientname) and filtering the exact mac-address but it keeps popping up in syslog.

Made by problems of the user i checked syslog and found this looping DISCOVER every some seconds. after checking the device again, repair some unusally drivers it worked just fine on other networks on different host, it was even able to renew "DHCP lease". So assuming its not the client, it is a server problem wich says dhcp to start a connection. all other users with laptop do not cause problems, it just works as expected.

i tryed allready rebooting, dhcp flush

**so i'd like to know how to stop this DHCP DISCOVER.** 
is there a terminal command i could use with `bootpd` or 
 `serveradmin settings dhcp` to stop that manually?

*maybe nice to know, i administrate this server remotely, so i can not turn off the connection at all, just rebooting and comming back*
and here a part of a anonymized syslog

```
....
05:35:14 server.example.com bootpd[336]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:35:14 server.example.com bootpd[336]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:35:22 server.example.com bootpd[336]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:35:22 server.example.com bootpd[336]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:35:38 server.example.com bootpd[336]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:35:38 server.example.com bootpd[336]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:35:52 server.example.com bootpd[336]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:35:52 server.example.com bootpd[336]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: server name server.example.com
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: interface en0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: interface ppp0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: dhcp: re-reading lease list
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: bsdpd: re-reading configuration
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: bsdpd: shadow file size will be set to 48 megabytes
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: bsdpd: age time 00:15:00
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: bsdpd: no sharepoints defined
05:36:41 server.example.com bootpd[387]: bootpd: NetBoot service turned off
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: server name server.example.com
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: interface en0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: interface ppp0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: re-reading configuration
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: shadow file size will be set to 48 megabytes
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: age time 00:15:00
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: no sharepoints defined
05:46:16 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bootpd: NetBoot service turned off
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: server name server.example.com
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: interface en0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: interface ppp0: ip 192.168.xxx.2 mask 255.255.255.0
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: dhcp: re-reading lease list
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: re-reading configuration
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: shadow file size will be set to 48 megabytes
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: age time 00:15:00
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bsdpd: no sharepoints defined
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: bootpd: NetBoot service turned off
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:47:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:48:05 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:48:05 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:49:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:49:57 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
05:50:05 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: DHCP DISCOVER [en0]: 1,**:**:**:**:**:**
05:50:05 server.example.com bootpd[33610]: OFFER sent <unknown> 192.168.xxx.12 pktsize 300
....
```

Comment: You have masked out important information; please edit it and restore the missing information: your RFC 1918 addresses.

Comment: What is the intent here?  This doesn't seem like it would cause any problem in a reasonable environment.

Answer (score 0):

this checklist solved it on server side..

1) terminal command

```
echo "add State:/Network/Interface/en0/RefreshConfiguration temporary" | sudo scutil
```

2.) turn off the net-switch / router

3.) turn on the router

4.) controll the device again

```
ipconfig getpacket en0
```

5.) turn on netboot service, wait 30sec

6.) turn off netboot service, wait 5min

7.) ACK Messages for all connections will show up, 
 the missleading `DHCP DISCOVER mac-id` should be gone!